# Notification click (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I have one notification, created in MainActivity's OnStop(). It looks like that:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (!finish){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(QUIT);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        // build notification
        // the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short
        n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Still working")
                .setContentText("Still getting data")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, n);
    }
}
```

It should reopen the MainActivity, but it is openning a new MainActivity, so I have two. What should I do for just open the same activity closed in OnStop()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the flag of the intent to include the following:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Or simply edit the manifest entry for MainActivity to include:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

More info on intent and possible flags [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and more info on launch modes [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

Comment: Is there anyway for resume the activity I have, instead creating a new one?

Comment: Given it is happening in onStop() I don't think you are able to do so.

Comment: I add ".addAction(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha, "Finalizar", pIntent)" to NotificationBuilder and "if (getIntent()!=null) finish(); " in MainActivity's OnCreate(), but the application isn't finishing when I click the notification.